How to force Heroku to install the leaflet package?
I have a small R Shiny application that runs perfectly on my local machine. I am now trying to deploy it on Heroku using the Heroku buildpack for R.
Everything seems to work well during deployment, and Heroku indicates that the deployment was successful. However, when I try to run the app, it fails because the leaflet package was not installed, despite it being listed in my init.R file.
Here is the relevant part of my init.R file:
# init.R
#
# Example R code to install packages if not already installed
#

my_packages = c("dplyr", "ggplot2","plotly","leaflet","readr")

install_if_missing = function(p) {
  if (p %in% rownames(installed.packages()) == FALSE) {
    install.packages(p, clean=TRUE, quiet=TRUE)
  }
}

invisible(sapply(my_packages, install_if_missing))```

 
**Error: Application Logs**
```2024-09-27T23:23:42.631327+00:00 app[web.1]: Error in library(leaflet) : there is no package called ‘leaflet’
2024-09-27T23:23:42.631328+00:00 app[web.1]: Calls: <Anonymous> ... sourceUTF8 -> eval -> eval -> ..stacktraceon.. -> library
2024-09-27T23:23:42.637364+00:00 app[web.1]: Execution halted
2024-09-27T23:23:42.683040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-09-27T23:23:42.707066+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed```


I have also tried the following alternative codes in the init.R:

CRAN version
install.packages('leaflet')
OR
Or Github version
if (!require('devtools')) install.packages('devtools') devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet')
OR
helpers.installPackages('dplyr', 'ggplot2','leaflet', 'readr')       All were usuccessfull

Trying quiet = FALSE would seem like a good place to start

The problem seems to reside with the "rgdal" dependency  ----->
==================================================
downloaded 1.9 MB
   * installing *source* package ‘terra’ ...
   ** package ‘terra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
   ** using staged installation
   configure: CC: gcc
   configure: CXX: g++ -std=gnu++14
   checking for gdal-config... no
   no
   configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
   ERROR: config


Seems to is a common issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76594555/heroku-gdal-config-missing-when-installing-r-packages-rgdal-terra

It's not {rgdal} (an R package) but GDAL (a system dependency). If you run remotes::system_requirements(os = "ubuntu-20.04", package = "leaflet") you'll see what needs to be installed on Ubuntu (the OS heroku uses) to be able to install leaflet. I'm not familiar with heroku, but you need to run apt-get install gdal-bin (and likewise for the other dependencies) before you run init.R

Thanks, don't know how to do that, but I will try.


remotes::system_requirements(os = "ubuntu-20.04", package = "leaflet")
[1] "apt-get install -y make"
[2] "apt-get install -y pandoc"
[3] "apt-get install -y libpng-dev"
[4] "apt-get install -y libgdal-dev"
[5] "apt-get install -y gdal-bin"
[6] "apt-get install -y libgeos-dev"
[7] "apt-get install -y libproj-dev"
[8] "apt-get install -y libsqlite3-dev"


Added an Aptfile and the Aptfile buildpack
WARNING: Use of the Aptfile file is NOT recommended
   W: No sandbox user '_apt' on the system, can not drop privileges
   W: GPG error: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified   the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8
   E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg InRelease' is not signed.

!     Push rejected, failed to compile R (shiny) app.
!     Push failed

Apparently I ay also need a bin/compile file
